# Django - How can I debug code which POST's when a bug seems to be in the view?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, formsets

I thought I would ask a broad question so I get a better understanding of Django and can more readily deal with any similar problems I may encounter. The specific issue which I am having is that I have written my first formset code, which renders the forms correctly but when posted no new objects are created.

I can see from the server that the form has been posted, I get no errors but no data has been added to my database (checked from django admin and manage.py shell). Perhaps it is possible to read what has been posted in a manage.py shell? I would like to be able to check whether the form posted its data correctly and it has been received by the view. Then I can see why either the data isn't posting correctly or the view isn't handling it correctly.

For the specific issue I will place my code below, in case it's a simple beginner error which one of you wizards can spot. I tried to follow and adapt [this tutorial](http://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html) for my own purposes.

Models.py

```
class Chunk(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    images = models.FileField()
    question = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    expected_completion_time = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    is_flagged = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Concept(Chunk):
    application = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    @property
    def mode(self):
        return "concept"


class Subconcepts(models.Model):
    subconcept = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    concept = models.ForeignKey(Concept, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.concept.name + ' - Subconcept'
```

forms.py

```
class ConceptForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Form for creating Concept objects
    class Meta:
        model = Concept
        fields = ['application', 'name', 'text', 'images', 'question', 'expected_completion_time', 'keywords', 'topic', 'course']


class SubconceptForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Form for creating Subconcept objects which are linked by ManyToOne fields to Concept objects
    class Meta:
        model = Subconcepts
        fields = ['subconcept']  # Concept field excluded as will be set in view on form submission


class BaseSubconceptFormset(BaseFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        # Validate that all subconcepts are unique
        if any(self.errors):
            return
        subconcepts = []
        duplicates = False

        for form in self.forms:
            if form.cleaned_data:
                subconcept = form.cleaned_data('subconcept')

                if subconcept:
                    if subconcept in subconcepts:
                        duplicates = True
                    subconcepts.append(subconcept)

                if duplicates:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(
                        'Each key feature must be unique',
                        code='duplicate_subconcept'
                    )
```

views.py

```
def testformsets(request):

    # Forms for creating a concept with appropriate subconcepts
    SubconceptFormset = formset_factory(SubconceptForm, formset=BaseSubconceptFormset)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        concept_form = ConceptForm(request.POST)
        subconcept_formset = SubconceptFormset(request.POST)

        if concept_form.is_valid() and subconcept_formset.is_valid():
            concept = concept_form.save()

            new_subconcepts = []

            for subconcept_form in subconcept_formset:
                subconcept = subconcept_form.cleaned_data.get('subconcept')
                new_subconcepts.append(Subconcepts(subconcept=subconcept, concept=concept))

            try:
                with transaction.atomic():
                    # Add all new subconcepts at once
                    Subconcepts.objects.bulk_create(new_subconcepts)

                    # And notify our users that it worked
                    messages.success(request, 'You have added new material')

            except IntegrityError:  # If the transaction failed
                messages.error(request, 'There was an error saving your concept.')
                return redirect('pomodoro/index.html')

    else:
        concept_form = ConceptForm()
        subconcept_formset = SubconceptFormset()

    context = {
        'concept_form': concept_form,
        'subconcept_formset': subconcept_formset
    }
    return render(request, 'pomodoro/formset_test.html', context)
```

Comment: Add logging statements to the view code.

Comment: `concept = concept_form.save` Did you mean to say `.save()` (with parentheses)?  Otherwise you're _referring_ to the save method, but you aren't _calling_ it.

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you for spotting that (errors_spotted_by_django_wizards += 1). You are correct and I have edited that. It would seem that that was not the only error however as there is still no data being saved to the database on form submission. Could you please tell me more about logging statements? I am not aware of this functionality. Perhaps there is some documentation which you could direct me towards?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html

Comment: Also see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add logging statements to your code.  A good place to start is to log the outcome of every decision and the result of every important function call, like so:

```
def myView(request):

    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(filename='mylog.log', level=logging.DEBUG)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        logging.debug('request.method=POST')
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        logging.debug('form=%s', form)

        if concept_form.is_valid():
            logging.debug('form is valid')
            myform = form.save()
            logging.debug('called form.save(), result=%s', myform)

        else:
            logging.debug('form is not valid')
    else:
        logging.debug('request.method is not POST')
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed. It has shown me where my error lies, now I need to work out how to solve it. Thanks again.